# Landed briefly in London for 9 hrs, can I return to the UK again without going home (Australia) first?

Tags: uk, international-travel, london, australian-citizens, stopovers

I hold an Australian passport and stopped in London on the way to Malta for 9 hrs and got passport stamped. Have been in Malta since.

Can I return if it has been over 90 days?

Comment: The UK does not have any restrictions about 90 days; and a 9 hour layover doesn't count as a day in the first instance. You can visit again right now if you want.

Comment: If you wish to be cold and wet and spend an incredible amount of money on mediocre food - you can do this, yes!   :-)

Answer (score 4):

[The visa policy for Aussie citizens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Australian_citizens#Visa_exemptions_and_requirements_for_the_United_Kingdom):

> Australian citizens are able to visit the United Kingdom for up to 6
>   months (or 3 months if they enter from the Republic of Ireland)
>   without the need to apply for a visa as long as they fulfil all of the
>   following criteria:
>
> - they do not work during their stay in the UK
> - they must not register a marriage or register a civil partnership during their stay in the UK
> - they can present evidence of sufficient money to fund their stay in the UK (if requested by the border inspection officer)
> - they intend to leave the UK at the end of their visit and can meet the cost of the return/onward journey
>     they have completed a landing card and submitted it at passport control unless in direct transit to a destination outside the Common Travel Area
>     if under the age of 18, they can demonstrate evidence of suitable care arrangements and parental (or guardian's) consent for their stay
>     in the UK

There are more links and some clauses (eg if you have a criminal conviction), but generally you can certainly visit without problem, as long as you can show onward travel and funds to support yourself if asked.

The UK doesn't have a 90-day rule, unlike Schengen/US limits.